# Vary XSLT transformation per input parameter iteration number

Tags: xml, xslt, param

I have posted my source XML and target XML and I need help in transforming it using XSLT. I am trying to split my source XML collection into different target XML documents. I would need to pass in the iteration number at runtime into XSLT.

Source XML:

---

```
<sou:rElement xmlns:sou="source.sample.com">
 <sou:Header>
    <sou:Elem1>SampleElementHeader</sou:Elem1>
 </sou:Header>
 <sou:Body>
     <sou:Elem2>
      <sou:Elem3>
          <sou:ElemCollection>
             <sou:Elements>
                    <sou:data>SomeData</sou:data>
             </sou:Elements>
             <sou:Elements>
                    <sou:data>SomeData1</sou:data>
             </sou:Elements>
             <sou:Elements>
                    <sou:data>SomeData2</sou:data>
             </sou:Elements>
             <sou:Elements>
                    <sou:data>SomeData3</sou:data>
             </sou:Elements> 
          </sou:ElemCollection>
      </sou:Elem3>
     </sou:Elem2>
 </sou:Body>
</sou:rElement>
```

---

Target XML:

---

```
First Iteration:

 <sou:rElement xmlns:sou="source.sample.com">
 <sou:Body>
     <sou:Elem2>
      <sou:Elem3>
          <sou:ElemCollection>
             <sou:Elements>
                    <sou:data>SomeData</sou:data>
             </sou:Elements>
          </sou:ElemCollection>
      <sou:Elem3>
     <sou:Elem2>
 </sou:Body>
</sou:rElement>

Second Iteration:

 <sou:rElement xmlns:sou="source.sample.com">
 <sou:Body>
     <sou:Elem2>
      <sou:Elem3>
          <sou:ElemCollection>
             <sou:Elements>
                    <sou:data>SomeData1</sou:data>
             </sou:Elements>
          </sou:ElemCollection>
      <sou:Elem3>
     <sou:Elem2>
 </sou:Body>
</sou:rElement>

Third Iteration:

 <sou:rElement xmlns:sou="source.sample.com">
 <sou:Body>
     <sou:Elem2>
      <sou:Elem3>
          <sou:ElemCollection>
             <sou:Elements>
                    <sou:data>SomeData2</sou:data>
             </sou:Elements>
          </sou:ElemCollection>
      <sou:Elem3>
     <sou:Elem2>
 </sou:Body>
</sou:rElement>

Fourth Iteration:

 <sou:rElement xmlns:sou="source.sample.com">
 <sou:Body>
     <sou:Elem2>
      <sou:Elem3>
          <sou:ElemCollection>
             <sou:Elements>
                    <sou:data>SomeData3</sou:data>
             </sou:Elements>
          </sou:ElemCollection>
      <sou:Elem3>
     <sou:Elem2>
 </sou:Body>
</sou:rElement>
```

---

Comment: Could you please post the XSLT you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:sou="source.sample.com">

  <xsl:param name="iteration" select="1"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sou:Header"/>

  <xsl:template match="sou:Elements">
    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::sou:Elements) + 1 = $iteration">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Applied to the following input XML document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sou:rElement xmlns:sou="source.sample.com">
  <sou:Header>
    <sou:Elem1>SampleElementHeader</sou:Elem1>
  </sou:Header>
  <sou:Body>
    <sou:Elem2>
      <sou:Elem3>
        <sou:ElemCollection>
          <sou:Elements>
            <sou:data>SomeData</sou:data>
          </sou:Elements>
          <sou:Elements>
            <sou:data>SomeData1</sou:data>
          </sou:Elements>
          <sou:Elements>
            <sou:data>SomeData2</sou:data>
          </sou:Elements>
          <sou:Elements>
            <sou:data>SomeData3</sou:data>
          </sou:Elements> 
        </sou:ElemCollection>
        <sou:Elem3>
          <sou:Elem2>
          </sou:Elem2>
        </sou:Elem3>
      </sou:Elem3>
    </sou:Elem2>
  </sou:Body>
</sou:rElement>
```

**Will yield the following output XML when `iteration` is set to 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sou:rElement xmlns:sou="source.sample.com">
  <sou:Body>
    <sou:Elem2>
      <sou:Elem3>
        <sou:ElemCollection>
          <sou:Elements>
            <sou:data>SomeData</sou:data>
          </sou:Elements>
        </sou:ElemCollection>
        <sou:Elem3>
          <sou:Elem2>
          </sou:Elem2>
        </sou:Elem3>
      </sou:Elem3>
    </sou:Elem2>
  </sou:Body>
</sou:rElement>
```

**And the desired output XML when `iteration` is set to 2 through 4 as well.**

Comment: This address my issue. Thanks a lot.